# Why does the Gamma distribution in SciPy have three parameters?

Tags: statistics, scipy

Usually, the Gamma distribution has two parameters: shape and scale (or alternatively shape and rate). However, it seems that in SciPy the Gamma distribution has three parameters: two shape parameters and a location parameter.

Does anyone know the mapping between the SciPy parameters of Gamma, and, e.g., the parameters in the definition given on wikipedia:

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gamma_distribution

Thanks!

Answer (score 20, accepted):

*All* the continuous distributions in scipy.stats have [location and scale parameters](https://www.itl.nist.gov/div898/handbook/eda/section3/eda364.htm), even those for which the location is not generally used.  For the gamma distribution, just leave the location at its default value 0.  If you are using the `fit` method, use the argument `floc=0` to ensure that it does not treat the location as a free parameter.

The shape and scale parameters in the scipy gamma distribution correspond to k and θ, respectively, in the wikipedia page.

Comment: Interestingly, the data that I'm fitting now fits the beta distribution better than Gamma. It used to fit Gamma pretty well when I didn't set floc=0. Any clue why this might happen if the location parameter for Gamma is not used?

Comment: Do you know why scipy chose such an exotic parametrization scheme for the gamma distribution? That must be the kind of error source that sinks ships and crashes probes into Mars.